# Converter json para Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Eu estou tentando converter json os dados em um dicionário.
Este json_teste para ser um tipo dict mas na verdade vem como um tipo list quando eu verifico com type(json1_data).

```
import json
json1_file = open('json_teste')
json1_str = json1_file.read()
json1_data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Comment: Uma dica: se vc abriu o arquivo, não precisa jogar todo o conteúdo em uma string pra depois ler o JSON, pode fazer de uma vez só: `json1_data = json.load(json1_file)`

Comment: Obrigado, pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provavelmente seu JSON é um array com um único  ou vários objetos dentro , então quando você o lê, você recebe uma lista com um dicionário dentro. Você pode acessar seu dicionário acessando o valor `json.loads(json1_str)[0]` na lista.